# how to refresh table property with SQLDirect Library in delphi 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-7

I want to ask how we could refresh all the table property in Delphi 7 and i am using SQLDirect Library.

I have try to open all the table property one by one, delete the altered field property and add those field again, but it's too many to open, so it takes more time .

Now i am trying to have the efficient way to refresh the table, like in vb6 with right click and refresh, is it possible to do it more efficient  ?.

Comment: If you simply want to refresh a table then just refresh it's dataset by using refresh method (`Table1.Refresh;`) or close and reopen it (`Table1.Colse; Table1.Open;`). If you want to refresh all Tables then just list all tables used and refresh it using one of the two methods above.

Comment: i have a changed field length in the query , now i have to reload the query field inside TSDQuery , to get the right length for the field, it's a lot of effort just to reload by remove and adding the field again in order to get the current field length, if it may how to done it efficiently ?